# Grabbing playlist urls from sites?

Tags: java, url, audio, audio-streaming

My current class is located below, i'm just wondering if there's any way for me to grab a URL from a site that has a playlist of music and use that instead of having to keep a .wav file in my project folder. This is my current specific class for this sound system.
Hope I can get some feedback, I'm trying to keep my project folder at minimum file size as much as possible! Thanks in advance.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package GUI.Music;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

/**
 *
 * @author Mod Den
 */
public class MusicPlayer {
    public static void sound(){
    InputStream in;
    try{
    in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Mod Den\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication18\\dist\\lib\\music.wav"));
    AudioStream audios = new AudioStream(in);
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audios);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You would want to open a connection to the URL by using `URLConnection` and then use it's input stream as the parameter to your `AudioStream`.  Also, on a side note, you should use reflection to call `sun.*` classes because they are only present in Oracle's JVM, and any users on other JVM distributions would be unable to use run your program.

Comment: could you show me how it's done? ;o

Comment: I can't right now, I'm about to head out on a 4 hour drive, but if no one else has answered by then, I'll write up an answer.  Until then, I encourage that you research streaming from a `URLConnection` and the other things I've mentioned, as it will be beneficial to you to become familiar with the documentation and learning process.  (Also, your name intrigues me).